# Create View with a join on the same content type

Tags: views

I am trying to create a View that produces 1 stop itineraries. I have a content type `"Route"`, with the following fields.

```
From To Method
```

The data looks like:

```
From | To | Method  
 A   | B  | Method 1  
 A   | Z  | Method 3  
 B   | C  | Method 3  
 Z   | C  | Method 3
```

If a user searches `"From: A"`, `"To: C",` the view should return:

```
From | To | From | To |  
 A   | B  |  B   |  C |  
 A   | Z  |  Z   |  C |
```

which ultimately results in B and Z as the intersection points (and a more friendly output to the user).

```
From | Via | To  
 A   |  B  | C  
 A   |  Z  | C
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to produce this join against the route table.

Any advice? I have even replicated the Route content type to `"Route 2"`, and attempted a relationship on the inner `"From"` and `"To"` fields of Route and Route 2, but cannot produce this expected output.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Install [Equi Join](https://www.drupal.org/project/equi_join) module

> The Equi Join module allows you to create relationships between
>   different entities based on an arbitrary field. This allows the use of
>   relationships in Views without having to add Node References to a
>   content type, which may not be an option when displaying data stored
>   on a third-party database or data provided through custom Views
>   handlers. That said, it works with nodes as well.

Using only a **single** content type `Route` create your view as follows:

1. Add your `from` and `to` fields.
2. Add a Relationship of `Equi Join: Content` and give it a name. Set Left field to `field_to` and Right field to `field_from`
3. Add a second set of `from` and `to` fields, but set the relationship on
   them to the new Relationship you added.
4. If you wish you can then either remove the first `To` field or the
   second `From` field.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I'll look into it further. I am receiving an SQL error at the moment, but the module is just what I need.   

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= field_to_airport.) ))) subquery' at line 3

Comment: Hm, I suspect its because my From and To fields are also node references. Could this be causing the error?

Comment: Yes. The to and from fields are just normal text fields in the content type. The Equi Join module allows you to make joins without references, solely on the fields.